# What is the best way to share data between nodeJs and PHP on the same server

Tags: php, node.js

I need nodeJs to communicate with PHP and PHP to return results to nodeJs and vice versa.

I am aware that dNode is a form of RPC module that can be put to use but I fear dNode is not scalable.

When I tried working with dNode, my server usually timeout due to maximum execution time of 120secs.

Also, dNode seem to capture results of exposed PHP classes on instantiation. Connection will have to be closed and reopened again before new variable can be used.

I just wanna know what is the least resource intensive way to enabling communication between nodeJs and PHP on the same server(localhost).

Comment: Can't you just create a simple REST api in node, which your PHP can consume to send and get data?